# .htaccess rewriterule is redirecting me to another site - why

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to do some work in `serve_each_drive.php` under the url `drive_for_london/?pid=12`

this is my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^drive_for_(.*)/$ http://web228.sydney.webhoster.ag/soputnik/serve_each_drive.php [L]
```

I want to keep the url `drive_for_london/?pid=12` and do the work in background. but the rule above is redirecting me to `serve_each_drive.php`. the url is becoming:

```
http://web228.sydney.webhoster.ag/soputnik/serve_each_drive.php
```

why? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct mod_rewrite behavior that target URL will externally redirect (hence change in your browser also) if you have full URL in the target. Since your target URL starts with `http://` therefore this redirection is happening.

To prevent this behavior you need to:

1. Make sure you're using URL without domain (internal to web server)
2. Make sure to not to use R flag (you are already doing it)

So change your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^drive_for_(.*?)/$ /soputnik/serve_each_drive.php [L,NC]
```

Also keep in mind above code assumes the URL on your page is: `http://web228.sydney.webhoster.ag/drive_for_london/?pid=12` and that will be internally forwarded to: `http://web228.sydney.webhoster.ag/soputnik/serve_each_drive.php?pid=12`